# Solving Hamming Distance of n bit-string with FFT?

Tags: algorithm, fft

Given n different bit strings, each one of them has the same length

Ex:

```
110111
100001
101000
001000
```

Calculate the minimum hamming distance between any two strings.

I know how to do it with just two strings, but how can we tell if we want to find the minimum across all of them? in O(nlogn)? I was thinking maybe it is possible that we can concatenate the strings together?

Comment: if max bit length is `b` you can do this in O(`b*2^b)` by generating a graph and doing BFS from given bit strings

Comment: This problem is similar (but more general and more complex ?) than the one of finding the minimum distance of a binary linear code. This  problem is inherently hard. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361046/minimum-distance-of-a-binary-linear-code)

Comment: What would be the maximum length of the bit string?

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur say b <= 20?